# Personlized Content for Automated E-mail

Tags: python

Sending out a e-mail that allows me to edit personalized content within the body of the e-mail. For example I would like to input the the 5 digit ext of a users phone. Then have it formatted into the body of the e-mail. Here is my code.

```
def instruct(send):
    pass

import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

from email.message import EmailMessage


email_user = 'E-mailaddress'
email_send = input('Enter address to Send e-mail to: ')
digits = input('Enter users 5 digit Phone Ext: ') #Users phone ext
subject = 'Voice Mail Instructions '




msg = EmailMessage()
msg['From'] = email_user
msg['To'] = email_send
msg['Subject'] = subject


#body of e-mail with formatted e-mail message
signature = """\
<html>
    <body>
      <p>Hi,<br>
      Attached Below are instructions for setting up voice mail at your {ext}. Please let me know if you have any questions.<br>
      <br>
      Thanks<br>
      </p>
    </body>
</html>

"""


msg.format(ext=digits)
msg.set_content(signature)


filename = 'mypdf.pdf'


with open(filename, 'rb') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()
    msg.add_attachment(content, maintype='application/pdf', subtype='pdf', filename=filename)
text = msg.as_string()


server = smtplib.SMTP('mailserver',25)
server.sendmail(email_user, email_send,text)
server.quit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I am understanding the question correctly, you want to alter the text to include the 5 digit number input by the user, in which case, try:

```
#body of e-mail with formatted e-mail message
signature = """\
<html>
    <body>
      <p>Hi,<br>
      Attached Below are instructions for setting up voice mail at your extension: {}. Please let me know if you have any questions.<br>
      <br>
      Thanks<br>
      </p>
    </body>
</html>

""".format(digits)
```

Comment: Boom! that did it added "format(ext=digits)" to the end.